# How do I concatenate a tag in React JSX?

Tags: reactjs

How do I concatenate these two variables into the a tag href in react jsx? I can't seem to get the quotations correct.

```
<div>Address: <a href='http://maps.google.com/?q=@{tooltipproperis.Lat},{tooltiproperis.Long}&t=h&z=2 targe=blank'>{tooltip.properties.Street}, {tooltip.properties.City}, {tooltip.properties.State},{tooltip.properties.Zip}</a></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misplaced a quote mark:

```
<div>
  Address:
  <a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=@{tooltipproperis.Lat},{tooltiproperis.Long}&t=h&z=2 targe=blank">
    {tooltip.properties.Street}, {tooltip.properties.City},{' '}
    {tooltip.properties.State}, {tooltip.properties.Zip}
  </a>
</div>
```